# Shallow and deep destructors?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

Imagine a list "a", and there's a copy constructor for lists which performs deep copying. If "b" is a list deep copied from "a", then both can be destroyed using simple destructors. This destructor should use *deep* destruction.

```
typedef struct list { void * first; struct list * next } list;

struct list * list_copy_constructor(const struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

void list_destructor(struct list * input);
```

Now imagine that you rename the copy constructor for lists as a deep copy constructor for lists, and add another shallow copy constructor for lists.

```
/**  Performs shallow copy. */
struct list * list_shallow_copy_constructor(const struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

/**  Performs deep copy. */
struct list * list_deep_copy_constructor(const struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

/**  Be warned performs deep destruction. */
void list_destructor(struct list * input);
```

The destructor, which performs a deep destruction, can be used paired with the deep copy constructor calls.

Once you used the shallow copy constructor for lists, you would need to know which of both lists **own** the elements, and then one of the lists (the list owning the elements), can be destroyed with the destructor, but for the list that doesn't own the elements, I would need to destroy it using a *shallow destructor* I would need to create, before destroying the list owning the elements.

```
/**  Performs shallow copy. */
struct list * list_shallow_copy_constructor(const struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

/**  Performs deep copy. */
struct list * list_deep_copy_constructor(const struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

/**  Performs shallow destruction. */
void list_shallow_destructor(struct list * input);

/**  Performs deep destruction. */
void list_deep_destructor(struct list * input);
```

But, the problem is, I don't recognize *shallow destructor* as a term in bibliography, so I thought I might be doing something wrong. **Am I doing something wrong?** E.g. should I be using smart pointers already instead of deep and shallow destructors?

Comment: I'm sorry, why have you replaced the C tag for the C++ tag?

Comment: Presumably because copy constructors aren't there in C.

Comment: I'm writing about deep and shallow copy constructors in a same class. Please tell me how that duality exists in C++!

Comment: Please tell me how copy constructors are in C :)

Comment: `struct list * list_copy_constructor(const struct list * input) REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;` is a copy constructor! ._.

Comment: @L.F. - C++ makes heavy use of the term, but it doesn't *own* it. A custom ADT in C can have an `ADT_clone` function, that's a copy constructor right there. It creates a new object from an existing one.

Comment: @StoryTeller and OP Oops, sorry for incorrectly assuming that you are referring to C++ terminology ...

Comment: @uprego - You may wish to add some code examples. It should prevent confusion with the C++ use of the term.

Comment: Tracking ownership is a reasonable approach for this, so you're not doing something "wrong". You will however also need to track lifetime. Either one of the 2 lists owns the nodes, and the other list's lifetime is constrained by the first list's lifetime. Or neither of the 2 lists owns the nodes, and both lists' lifetimes are constrained by some other object that owns the nodes.

Comment: It doesn't matter which list owns the elements. "and then one of the lists (the list owning the elements), can be destroyed with the destructor" No. It doesn't matter which list "owns" the elements. It only matters which list is destroyed first. The list that is destroyed first needs to be destroyed by shallow destructor. The other list (the first list or the copy) need to free the elements.

Comment: StoryTeller: edited, thanks. Sander De Dycker: understood, thanks. Gerhardh: understood, edited, thanks.

Comment: @1737973 choose the answer. Give guys the bounty

Comment: Are you sure that C is a suitable language for what you are doing? Copy constructors and destructors are OOP concepts, and OOP doesn't have native support in C and needs to be emulated with boilerplate.

Comment: I'd say it's more natural for containers, such as lists, not to own its elements, and thus shallow copy constructor and destructor should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of deep or shallow exists only in the mind of the programmer, and in C++ it is very arbitrary. By default raw pointer members are not deep destroyed when an object is destroyed, which you might call shallow, but you can write extra code in your object destructor to destroy deeply. On the other hand any members that have destructors get their destructors called, which you might call deep, and there is no way to avoid that. Exactly the same mechanism applies for the default copy and assignment, so is equally impossible to say an object is wholly deep or shallow copied or destroyed at a glance.

So the distinction is not really a property of object destructors, but their members.

Of course, now the question is about C again, but still mentions smart pointers. In C you have to decide what philosophy you want to implement, as there is no concept of destruction. If you follow a C++-like philosophy of having destruction functions for each type of member, and having them deep-call.

Having said that there are a number of strategies you might consider that would potentially produce a leaner model:

If /all/ the members of a particular container are owned or /all/ not owned, then a simple flag in the container for whether to destroy /all/ children is an adequate model.

If /all/ the objects are shared with another container, or this might be the last/only such container for a particular set of content, you could keep a circular list of sharing containers. When the destructor realises it is the last container it could destroy /all/ the content. On the other hand, you could simply implement this model with a shared_ptr to the one container instance, and when the last pointer is released then the container is destroyed.

If individual items in the container may be shared in arbitrary ways, then make it a container of shared_ptr to each item of content. This is the most robust model, but may have costs in terms of memory usage. Ultimately, somewhere there needs to be a reference count (though circular lists of referees are also good, it is much harder to mutex across threads) In C++ shared_ptr this is implemented using a stub, but in your own C objects, this is probably a counter member in the child object.

Comment: Quote of the day `The concept of deep or shallow exists only in the mind of the programmer, and in C++ it is very arbitrary.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have lists with shared elements be correctly destructed, you cannot simply use "shallow destructors". Destructing them all with shallow destructors results in elements still residing in memory and being leaked. It also doesn't look good to mark one of the lists having a deep destructor while others having shallow ones. If you first destroy the list with deep destructor, others will have dangling pointers which you can accidentally access. So it looks like shallow destructor is not a well-recognized term simply because it is not of a great use. You just have destructors: functions that destroy the stuff that you objects conceptually own.

Now, for the particular task of sharing elements in lists and destroying everything in time shared pointers seem to be a reasonable solution. A shared pointer is conceptually a pointer to a struct consisting of two elements: an actual object (list element) and reference counter. Copying the shared pointer increases the counter; destroying the shared pointer decreases the counter and destructs the struct with object & counter if the counter fell to 0. In this scenario, each list own its copies of shared pointers, but the list elements themselves are owned by shared pointers rather than a list. Due to the shared pointer destruction semantics there is no trouble with destroying all the shared pointer copies that the list owns (the destructor doesn't deallocate memory unless there are no references left), so there is no need for distinguishing "shallow" and "deep" destructors, as shared pointers will take care of deleting themselves in time automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As you already suspected, your design is weird. Think about it: if you are going to "shallow copy" a list, why not just take a pointer of it? "Shallow copy" has no use outside of a classroom, where it is only useful to explain what a "deep copy" is.

You either want multiple users to have independent lists, that can be used and destroy independently of the each other, or you want one user to "own" the list, and the others just point to that list. Your idea of "shallow copy" has no advantage over a simple pointer, but is much more complex to handle.

What is actually useful is having multiple "lists" but with shared data, where each user has its own "shared copy" of the list that can be used and destroyed independently, but points to the same data, and will only really be deallocated when the last user has destroyed it. This is a very common pattern usually handled by an algorithm called [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), and is implemented by many libraries and languages, like Python, glib, and even in C++ as the smart pointer `std::shared_ptr`.

If you are using C, you may want to add support to reference counting to your `struct list`, and it is not very difficult: just add a field `unsigned reference_count;` and set it to 1 when it is allocated. Decrement when destroyed, but only really deallocate if `reference_count == 0`, in which case there are no more users and you must do a "deep deallocation". You would still have only one destructor function, but two copy constructors:

```
/**  Performs shared copy.
 *
 * Actually, just increments reference_count and returns the same pointer.
 */
struct list * list_shared_copy_constructor(struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

/**  Performs deep copy.
 *
 * reference_count for the new copy is set to 1.
 */
struct list * list_deep_copy_constructor(const struct list * input)
REQUIRE_RETURNED_VALUE_CAPTURE;

/**  Performs destruction. */
void list_shallow_destructor(struct list * input);
```

If you are actually using C++, as you hinted in your question, then simply use `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

> But, the problem is, I don't recognize shallow destructor as a term in bibliography, so I thought I might be doing something wrong. Am I doing something wrong?

The point of the destructor (or in C just *myobject_destroy(myobject*)*) is to clean up the resources the instance holds (memory, os handles, ...). Whether you need a "shallow destructor" or a "deep destructor" depends on the way you decided to implement your object, as long as it does its job to cleanup stuff.

If you are using modern C++ stack allocation and smart pointers are your friend, because they manage memory by themselves.